# SOAP response class not assigned (nil)

Tags: delphi, soap, soap-client

I am using Delphi 10.2.3 to consume a SOAP web service. My problem is web service replies are not assigned to response classes defined in wsdl generated using `WSDLImp.exe`.

I see that raw response XML contains all information in it as can be seen below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
X-HP-CAM-COLOR: V=1;ServerAddr=5F+cgNOCZPdfvCQ4naSfjw==;GUID=1|xpjJ6o0v_kd3rKz0c1ASIUXW--xZpHqeH8lJ3S2l30SxOi2DzpzfGfLpdqdxt0lg|L2VhcnNpdi93cy9FYXJzaXZXZWJTZXJ2aWNl
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2018 15:54:46 GMT
Server: EARSIV
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=157680000
Set-Cookie: cookiesession1=1BEDB4A4PX73WJCTCIRPOUP46FNNFC28;Path=/;HttpOnly

1da
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:faturaOlusturResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.earsiv.uut.cs.com.tr/"><return xmlns=""><resultCode>AE00067</resultCode><resultExtra></resultExtra><resultText>Web servis çağrısı "input" alanından gerekli bilgiler elde edilemedi. Eksik alanlar: null bu alan(lar)ın boş olmadığından emin olunuz!</resultText></return></ns2:faturaOlusturResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
0
```

`return` in `faturaOlusturResponse` is `nil` as I see while debugging. Trying to access to `return.resultCode` raises an access violation.

What you see is correct that there are garbage chars just before the line XML starts and right after it. I suspected that maybe the reason.

But;

1- I see [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) has no problem parsing this and displaying formatted XML view with all correct information.

2- I tried to use `OnAfterExecute()` event of `THTTPRIO`. I see that `SOAPResponse.Size` is 474 which is equal to XML line length in above raw response.

I cannot think of what maybe the problem and could not fix it. Internet searches did not help.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

WSDL URL: https://earsiv.efinans.com.tr/earsiv/ws/EarsivWebService?wsdl

**EDIT:**
Consuming web service method is done using `AFaturaOlustur()` function below. There is `SetSecurityHeader()` procedure which requires another unit code. I did not include them all not to post a lot of code in here. Json routines are from [mORMot](https://synopse.info/fossil/wiki/Synopse+OpenSource) framework. There are some constants used in some parts of the code as well. When I read file `response.xml` written in `HTTPRIO1AfterExecute()` procedure after running function, there is complete xml. It is identical to the one in raw response above:

```
class procedure TMyType.HTTPRIO1AfterExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPResponse: TStream);
var
  List: TStringList;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create();
  try
    SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
    List.LoadFromStream(SOAPResponse);
    List.SaveToFile('response.xml');
  finally
    List.Free();
  end;
end;

function AFaturaOlustur(const Input: TFaturaOlusturInput; const GidenBelgeFormati: TGidenBelgeFormatlari; const GidenDosya, GelenDosya: string): Boolean;
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
  WS: EarsivWebService;
  Request: faturaOlustur;
  Response: faturaOlusturResponse;
  Json: RawUTF8;
begin
  if not TFile.Exists(GidenDosya) then
  begin
    LastError := 'AFaturaOlustur(): GidenDosya mevcut değil!';
  end;

  RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  RIO.OnAfterExecute := TMyType.HTTPRIO1AfterExecute;
  RIO.URL := URLEArsivFatura;
  WS := (RIO as EarsivWebService);
  SetSecurityHeader(WS);

  Json := RecordSaveJSON(Input, TypeInfo(TFaturaOlusturInput));

  Request := nil;
  Response := nil;
  try
    Request := faturaOlustur.Create();
    Request.input := string(Json);
    Request.fatura := belge.Create();
    case GidenBelgeFormati of
      UBL: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.UBL;
      CSXML: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.CSXML;
      HTML: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.HTML;
      PDF: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.PDF;
      CUSTOM: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.CUSTOM;
      PDF_CUSTOM: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.PDF_CUSTOM;
      PDF_UBL: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.PDF_UBL;
      CSXML1: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.CSXML1;
      CSXML2: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.CSXML2;
      CSXML3: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.CSXML3;
      PDF_CSXML1: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.PDF_CSXML1;
      PDF_CSXML2: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.PDF_CSXML2;
      PDF_CSXML3: Request.fatura.belgeFormati := belgeFormatiEnum.PDF_CSXML3;
    end;
    Request.fatura.belgeIcerigi := ToByteDynArray(TFile.ReadAllBytes(GidenDosya));

    try
      Response := WS.faturaOlustur(Request);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        LastError := 'AFaturaOlustur(): ' + E.Message;
        Exit(False);
      end;
    end;
    Result := Assigned(Response.return);
    if Result then Result := Response.return.resultCode = rcSuccess;
    if Result then
    begin
      TFile.WriteAllBytes(GelenDosya, ToBytes(Response.output.belgeIcerigi));
    end
    else
    begin
      LastError := 'AFaturaOlustur(): ' + Response.return.resultText;
    end;
  finally
    Request.Free();
    Response.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think SOAP is the issue. More importantly: How are you using the generated class in your code?

Comment: I imported your SOAP and I have to admit your SOAP is one of kind. This is my first time to see such design. Can I see how your code on how you consumed your functions?

Comment: Added code showing how I consume SOAP in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is...unusual. The wsdl tool should normaly generate a unit named soap.pas. This unit should be used wherever you need it. In this unit you should find a base interface and its corresponding create function. However! Your WSDL is...um...how to put it? Complex? I can't help here.

Comment: I added myself a web service wrapper unit for easier use. Otherwise, you are right about normal use case of SOAP. Thanks.

Comment: I can't help too. Too complex to understand in one sitting. Can other languages(PHP, c#, android) can consume your web service? if not, its better you re-code it that other languages can consume it.

Comment: C# can definitely consume it. Web Service owner provides C# example codes. Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough to code with C#. Also, it has to be Delphi itself to consume this time. I know I can use `OnAfterExecute()` event of RIO and parse that response XML manually. I simply tried to avoid that it seems I will have to. Thanks.